# jQuery dynamically update data keys & values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a function that gets all data-attributes dynamically from an element. For e.g.:

```
<button id="button" data-key1="title" data-key2="content">Button 1</button>
<button id="changeButtonData">Change data for button 1</button>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $buttonData = $(this).data();
    console.log($buttonData);
}

$(document).on('click', '#changeButtonData', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //edit existing data-keys value
    $('#button').data('data-key1', 'newtitle');
    //store new data-key on element
    $('#button').data('data-key3', 'new');
}
```

The problem is, if i click the first button and check the console log, it will show `data-key1="title"` and `data-key2="content"`

And if i click the 2nd button afterwards, and click the first button again to fire the console logging again, it won't display the new replaced data-attributes or the new data-tags.

Anyone got an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because when you set the `data` attribute you should omit the `data-` prefix, eg: `$('#button').data('key3', 'new');`. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#changeButtonData', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#button').data({
        'key1': 'newtitle',
        'key3': 'new'
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ftwgd7e3/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work (I'm on Safari 8) - I was testing this out and had the same idea but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: I just tried it on Safari 8.0.3 for OSX and it worked fine. What makes you say that it did not work? Don't forget that the attributes themselves will not be changed in the DOM - jQuery stores them in an internal cache.

Comment: Aha thanks that helps :) I couldnt find that info the docs immediately. Annoying, though.

Comment: Yeah, I just edited my previous comment. jQuery does indeed store data attributes in an internal cache for performance benefits - you will see no change in the DOM, this is correct behaviour.

Comment: Okay thats the thing then.